# Meteor cannot start when using Meteorhacks:npm, nami package; cannot access localhost:3000

Tags: meteor, npm, asterisk, asteriskami

I am using npm nami package inside Meteor app to listen to events from an Asterisk server. In server side, I have this code:

```
namiLib = Meteor.npmRequire "nami"
namiConfig =
    "host": "..."
    "port": 5038
    "username": "..."
    "secret": "...
nami = new namiLib.Nami namiConfig
```

If I remove the line nami = new namiLib.Nami namiConfig, the server runs fine. But with that line, the server stops at following step, and I cannot access http://localhost:3000

[image: Nami package prevent Meteor from starting]

Any idea to help resolve this issue?

Comment: can you provide full console error in text format ?

Comment: there was no error, it just blocked Meteor from executing. The image shows all output from console.

Comment: anyway, I used other package instead of Nami to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I used a different package, which is [asterisk-manager](https://github.com/pipobscure/NodeJS-AsteriskManager), for the same purpose and it solved my problem. The issue should be Nami package itself.

Comment: Have you filed the issue with the Nami package?

Comment: Not yet, I just thought that Nami package owner might not know Meteor. I'll file the issue and see if they have a solution.